# currentdomain.setdata not working

Tags: c#, configuration

I have 3 workstations all opening and using the same code from TFS.

On 2 of those computers `appdomain.currentdomain.setdata("APP_CONFIG_FILE", configLocation)` picks up and loads the correct config keys. **One 1 it doesn't**.

Can anyone tell me why?

The file at `configLocation` is present and the path leads to the file. The actual config file is the **EXACT** same used by the 2 working computers.

It seems as if the 1 computer is not using the right config file or has already loaded a config, but why would it work for the other 2 then?

Comment: what version of .net is running on all 3 of the machines? have you looked at the Machine.Config file on all 3 of the machines as well to compare the settings..?

Comment: We are all using .NET 4.0. What specifically about the machine.config should I look at? How does that affect the loading?

Comment: I only ask that because I know that besides App.config and Web.config, machine.config file can also have things to do with loading / running an application. and if you need to know what you are looking for, try using a program like `Compare` to compare the 3 files against one another.. perhaps there is an error in the loading of the application and it never reaches the line of code where you are trying to read the .config settings also it would help if you would provide or show some code where you are loading the values. also show the .config section where you store these values.

Comment: it's probably something simple and one can't tell if they have zero access to what code you are look at ..

Comment: I'm sure it is something small and simple. Those are always the hardest to figure out. I didn't see anything with the machine.config. I look at it again. Thanks for your help